# Unable to get data after submiting the form in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I checked most of the question asked about this but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have this IActionResult that gets data and it works

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult AddUser(SearchViewModel model)
        {
            
            model.Location = new List<Location>();
            foreach (Location loc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Location)))
            {
                
                model.Location.Add(loc);
            }
            model.FoundRoles = new List<Roles>();
            if (roleManager.Roles != null)
            {
                foreach (var role in roleManager.Roles)
                {
                    Roles roles = new Roles
                    {
                        RoleId = role.Id,
                        RoleName = role.Name
                    };
                    model.FoundRoles.Add(roles);


                }

            }
           
            return View(model);
        }
```

Now in HttpPost when I click the submit button the data is lost it returns Null so I copied the same code in the get request into the post but it doesn't work it's ignored

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult AddUser(SearchViewModel profile, string id, string button, List<User> users)
        {

             if(ModelState.IsValid) 
            {
                //Some code here
            }  
            
                profile.Location = new List<Location>();
                foreach (Location loc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Location)))
                {
  
                    profile.Location.Add(loc);
                }
                profile.FoundRoles = new List<Roles>();
                if (roleManager.Roles != null)
                {
                    foreach (var role in roleManager.Roles)
                    {
                        Roles roles = new Roles
                        {
                            RoleId = role.Id,
                            RoleName = role.Name
                        };
                        profile.FoundRoles.Add(roles);


                    }

                }
            
            return View(profile);

        }
```

In my View I'm using a for loop just like others suggested in other questions. Also I tried using hidden fields but nothing works

How can I fix this

Comment: what do you mean by data when you say "data is lost it returns Null"

Comment: Hi @r2000_na, could you please share your view? Also please share your model design.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do some debugging to actually explain **what** isn't working. If it is the SearchViewModel that is arriving at your server as null, that may be because it's missing "FromBody" or "FromForm" in the function arguments section.

You **probably** want something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult AddUser([FromForm] SearchViewModel profile, [FromForm] string id, [FromForm] string button, [FromForm] List<User> users)
```

If not "FromForm", try "FromBody", but it's not easy to suggest much more without more detailed information

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I managed to solve the issue in different way

Comment: No worries! I'm actually curious as to how you fixed it, are you willing to explain?